# Windows Azure deployment keeps a old version of the Silverlight application

Tags: azure

I have a small solution that is composed out of 2 main projects a Mvc4 Web Api and a silverlight 5 Application. I've configured and deploy the application initially on the Azure platform and it all went great, but ever since when I deploy again the silverlight project does not get pushed and the online site has the old version.

I should mention all works great with the azure simulator on my local dev machine.

Anybody had a similar issue?

Regards,

Comment: did you wipe your browser cache? remote desktop to the machine to ensure that the file was updated?

Comment: Thanks Simon that is not the case, I did cleared the cache, I had those problems with the old fashion deployment

Comment: are you using webdeploy or azure packages? If you are using azure packages did you upgrade or also try creating a new deployment? Are you sure the silverlight project is built correctly? You could for example be running the Debug configuration in local emulation and deploying Release where a project might me unchecked in the build config ..

Comment: Thank you for your reply Simon, I am using azure packages, I did try a new deploy (deleted and redeployed) and it worked the first time but at the second deployment it was still using the old version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,

So after pulling my hair out, I finally figured out.

I have to change the build configuration to release in VS do a rebuild and then do publish because apparently the **azure project does not do rebuild on the project when you publish it.**

Answer (score 3):

I would suspect first (as Simon suggests) that the browser likely still has the previous client cached and loads that instead of downloading your new client.

You can use the version number in the code on your page that hosts the silverlight app to help.  While it's easy for you to clear the cache - you don't really want to have to tell users to do that whenever you update.

Set the version to whatever your latest assembly version is (silverlight client project assembly), this will force the browser to download the client if the cached version is a lower number.

```
<param name="source" value="AppPath/App.xap?version=2.0.0.6"/>
```

Comment: That seems like a great/smart workaround for that issue. Does that just trick the browser into assuming that the xap changes because of the new URL or is there any actual handling of the version param?
Especially when using continuous integration/versioned builds this should work very well.

Comment: it does handle the version parameter, the xap path/url can be identical - as long as you increment the assembly version and the version tag together the browser will load the new xap.  This was essentlial for me as I have an application whose silverlight client gets updated regularly.

Comment: it's a good comment but it does not solve my issue, I've recreated the virtual machines and the deploy worked again for the first time and them successive updates again fail to update the xaml

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you'll need to identify the source of the problem (is it a client side problem where you have a caching issue or not). Even though you say caching isn't the problem we'll need to be sure about this first.

What I suggest is that you do the following first:

1. Activate Remote Desktop on your role
2. Connect through RDP and save this file to the role: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290 (fciv.exe)
3. Find the *.xap file (usually in E:\sitesroot) and get its checksum (using fciv.exe)
4. Modify the Silverlight project locally (maybe change a label or move around an element) to make sure its hash has changed.
5. Redeploy the application
6. Connect through RDP and use fciv.exe to get the checksum of the *.xap file once again
7. Compare both checksums

If the checksums are different, then it means that the deployment worked correctly and the Silverlight xap has been updated. If the checksum is the same, the problem lies with the deployment.

Please let us know the result so we can help you find the solution.

Comment: ok, so the xap file checksum is the same after 2 consecutive deploys (I made some small changes each time)

Comment: So you are updating an existing deployment? Is there a specific reason for not deleting+deploying or staging/swapping?
Are you deploying azure or web packages?

Comment: Deploying Azure, by right click publish on the azure project, can you point me to a tutorial with the other deployment methods?